# Parsing HTML contained in API call response

Tags: python, api, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to parse HTML that's contained within the response of an API call in Python 3.7 (requests + BS4).

Say I want to parse out the article URLs from a [response like this one](https://www.washingtonpost.com/pb/api/v2/render/feature/?service=prism-query&contentConfig=%7B%22url%22:%22prism://prism.query/ap-articles-by-site-id,/world%22,%22offset%22:0,%22limit%22:5%7D&customFields=%7B%22isLoadMore%22:false,%22offset%22:0,%22maxToShow%22:50,%22dedup%22:true%7D&id=f00boImX29Vv3s&rid=&uri=/world/).

I'm able to get the "rendering" entry of the response which seemingly contains the HTML I'd like to parse, however, when I pass the text along to Beautiful Soup's HTML parser, it does not seem to work as expected (unable to locate HTML tags of any kind):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = """https://www.washingtonpost.com/pb/api/v2/render/feature/?service=prism-query&contentConfig={%22url%22:%22prism://prism.query/ap-articles-by-site-id,/world%22,%22offset%22:0,%22limit%22:5}&customFields={%22isLoadMore%22:false,%22offset%22:0,%22maxToShow%22:50,%22dedup%22:true}&id=f00boImX29Vv3s&rid=&uri=/world/"""

r = requests.get(url).json()

soup = BeautifulSoup(r['rendering'], 'html.parser')

links_html = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class":"headline x-small normal-style text-align-inherit "})
links = []
for div in links_html:
    links.append(div.find('a', href = True)['href'])
```

Am I wrong in my assumption that the "rendering" entry in the response is raw HTML?

Comment: Please share your code. Also ensure lxml installed and try using lxml parser.

Comment: if you check my answer, you'll see that the beautiful soup api is working and it's performing on the html, but something's probably wrong with your `find_all` incovation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the `json` library (or in hindsight, `Request.json()`), because whatever link you're visiting isn't actually a website, but what seems to be an api on top of it that gives you the html along with encoding, content type, and some other things that won't be necessary.

Here's how I did it.

```py
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> r = requests.get("https://www.washingtonpost.com/pb/api/v2/render/feature/?service=prism-query&contentConfig=%7B%22url%22:%22prism://prism.query/ap-articles-by-site-id,/world%22,%22offset%22:0,%22limit%22:5%7D&customFields=%7B%22isLoadMore%22:false,%22offset%22:0,%22maxToShow%22:50,%22dedup%22:true%7D&id=f00boImX29Vv3s&rid=&uri=/world/")
>>> bs = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
>>> first_div = bs.find("div", class_="moat-trackable")
>>> first_div
>>> import json
>>> html_dict = json.loads(r.content)
>>> html_dict
{'rendering': '<div class="moat-trackable ...'}
>>> html_dict.keys()
dict_keys(['rendering', 'encoding', 'contentType', 'pageResources', 'externalResources', 'httpHeaders'])
>>> bs = BeautifulSoup(html_dict["rendering"], 'html.parser')
>>> first_div = bs.find("div", class_="moat-trackable")
>>> first_div
<div class="moat-trackable
```

Comment: Fiddling with your example led me to the issue with my implementation. Exact matching the class of the divs I'm interested was not working (seemingly due to the escaping character backlashes in the HTML?). Approximate matching the class name did the trick.

Thanks!